# Evil keyboard movement extends mouse selection

Tags: evil, mouse, selection

**My Setup**

- Emacs 28.1
- Evil version 1.15.0
- Gnome 42.4 wayland

**Observed Behavior**

- In default emacs (GUI), with no init file, if you highlight a region with mouse 1 and then use a keyboard movement, **the highlighted region disappears**.
- If you load evil and nothing else, then do the same, the region **does not disappear** and, in fact, will be **extended as you move** from the keyboard. In addition, the *i* command does not work to get into insert mode. This behavior is the same as it would be if you had used *v* to highlight the region instead of the mouse.

The latter behavior is problematic for my workflow because if I'm working in another window and click over to emacs, I often inadvertently highlight at least a little bit of text. I then get confused when I can't insert and there is a region following me around like I stepped on something sticky.

I'm having a hard time zeroing in on why this behavior occurs or finding a way to make the highlighted region behave the same as it would under non-evil Emacs. Do you know if this is a bug or an expected evil behavior? How would I go about changing it?

=== EDIT ===

I just tried this in gvim and the behavior is the same as the default behavior in evil. Evil considers deviation from the way things work in vim to be a bug, so my guess is this was implemented this way on purpose. I would still love to know how to un-implement it. Anyone who has another idea on where to look for the source of this will be a hero.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the behavior.  I suspect a bad setting for the variable `transient-mark-mode` (which see).  I'm not an `evil` user myself, but in my basic test, it looked like dragging the mouse invoked both `evil-mouse-drag-region` *and* `mouse-set-region` (which I learned via `C-h k` and then dragging to set a selection). I can't tell whether that is expected or not, but maybe it gives you (or someone else) a thread to pull.

Answer (score 1):

The evil folks have addressed this issue--gotta love the emacs community. You can now change the behavior so that text highlighted by the mouse will become unhighlighted when a keyboard command is issued. You need to put the following in your init

```
(setq evil-transient-mouse-selection t)
```